# Saving objects in two ways, what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning Angular by following this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes). No what I don't get is why is there two ways of saving/editing an object? They don't really explain it.

first way (in the index.js router):

```
router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

second way (in the mongoose model):

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comment: None of this has anything to do with Angular. Angular is just a frontend framework; it never interacts with your server/database beyond REST calls.

Comment: @JoeClay sorry, got I had some Angular stuff in my head and got the tag there by accident :)

Comment: No problem! It's easily done when you're first starting with all the MEAN stack stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is a normal Mongoose save in which you create a new object from the schema. The second is having a method defined in the schema to handle the save.

```
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};
```

For example, assuming I already have a saved post and I want to upvote it. I can have a route like this:

```
router.put('/post/:id/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (error, post) {
    post.upvote(function(error, post) {
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
});
```

In simple terms, the code above makes use of the inbuilt "upvote" method that is already defined in the Schema, so all objects created from the Schema will have an "upvote" method that will increase the number of upvotes. It is the same thing as doing this:

```
router.put('/post/:id/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (error, post) {
    post.upvotes += 1;
    post.save(function(error, post) {
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
});
```

Just that it is cleaner and saves you a few keystrokes.

Comment: Got it! But so it's better to do edits is better to have in the schema instead of router?

Comment: None is the better than the other, just a case of personal preference. But if I decide to do edits in Schema methods, I will do that all through, same goes go doing edits in router functions. So consistency is the key. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

The two ways are actually the same.
In the first example a new instance of `Post` is created. The `save` is called on this instance because it exists on `PostSchema` (inherited from Mongoose `Schema`).

In the second example we define a new method on `PostSchema` so when invoked, `this` refers to the instance of the `Post`.
The `cb` parameter is a callback which is normally a function.

Look at this example.

```
router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        var callback = function(err, post) {
            console.log("Upvoted");
            res.json(post);   
        }
        post.upvote(callback);        
    });
});
```

Here a new post is created with one upvote by default.
A new instance of `Post` is created and saved in the db. After save, `upvote` method is called. After the upvote was saved in the db, the new post is returned in the response.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this, it's always helpful to get different insight.